# How can I read a text file in android with Turkish characters?

Tags: java, android, text, localization

I want to read a text file and I can read with below written code. But my text file include Turkish characters like "ü", "ç", "ğ", "ö"... When I read that text file, I can see these characters. For example, my word which written in text file is "okçu" but I see on my phone like "ok?u". How can fix it?

```
public static String readTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) {
        InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

        InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
        String line;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                stringBuilder.append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();

    }
```

Comment: Is the text file utf-8 encoded or in a turkish charset?

Comment: Which is the app that generated the txt? under which OS? You most likely will have to resave your txt with **UTF-8** encoding (possibly, with UNIX line terminators - not mandatory)

Comment: I dont know utf-8 but only It includes turkish character. The solution is probably relevant to UTF-8 encoding. But I couldnt find the solution. How can I resave with UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I received the response from my `HttpClient` for the first time. I managed to solve it by specifying the encoding within the `InputStreamReader` object's instantiation. I hope it might help you as well.

```
InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF8"),8);
```